# Communicating to ESP8266 with different Wi-Fi IP address

Tags: android, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm new to ESP2866 and Android development. I have set my ESP8266 at static IP address which connects with a Wi-Fi router. I want to access my ESP8266 module from different Wi-Fi through my android app.This app is connected to firebase. Is it possible to access ESP2866 from any Wi-Fi connection through android app?. If so, please let me know how?

P.S. I want Wifi module to communicate through different wifi connection.
Thankyou for help
Regards,

Comment: `Through which I'm able to communicate with the same IP address` ?? Unclear what you mean by that.

Comment: `I want to access my ESP8266 module from different Wi-Fi IP address through my android app`. Your android app will run on another device. So this device will have a different ip address of course. Both devices should be in the same wlan. In your setup the Android device is probably connected to the esp? It is unclear what your problem is. Is the esp an AP or a wifi client?

Comment: yes, all you need to know is the IP. a static IP for the ESP is recommended.

Comment: @greenapps My ESP is connected to IP address suppose 192.168.101 (that's the IP which is set for ESP) , In my app I connect through my wifi and feed in 192.168.101 to connect to the ESP to establish the connection. Basically I want to establish WAN connection for the WiFi module and the app.

Comment: This might help you- https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/how-to-make-your-devices-ip-address-static-port-forward-a-practical-demo-part-1/

Comment: `My ESP is connected to IP address`. Nonsense. Your esp isconnected to a wifi router. Or your esp acts as a hotspot/AP. Now start telling your setup how you use it.

Comment: @greenapps My ESP is set to an dynamic ip address and it acts like a webserver. and one more thing please be patient I'm new to this my terminologies are quite week w.r.t to this topic. So bear with me.

Comment: @greenapps My apologizes its a static IP address

Comment: You still did not tell if the esp is connected to a wifi router or is acting as hotspot/access point. I have patience but if you just dont answer questions...

Comment: @greenapps thankyou for your patience :), My ESP is connected to a wifi router, and I can access ESP using my app on different wifi present in the same room. but this doesn't work when I try accessing it from different location wifi.

Comment: @Rasi thank you for the link have gone through it will give it a try

Comment: @ra22 Yes if still you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: @rasi I will :)

Comment: @ra22 As you are saying, you set 192.168... ip address, which are accessible from same room, the reason behind is, they are private ip address series which are only accessible from same WIFI. Those series present in all networks.

Comment: `I can access ESP using my app on different wifi present in the same room.` ??? That makes no sense. I think you mean: `I can access ESP using my app on an Android device that is connected to the same wifi router..`

Comment: `but this doesn't work when I try accessing it from different location wifi. `??? Also pretty unclear. Do you mean:  `but this doesn't work when I try accessing it from a different wifi router . `

Comment: @greenapps yes you are right! my bad English, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achieved by "port forwarding method" please follow the steps as suggested by @rasi [Link](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/how-to-make-your-devices-ip-address-static-port-forward-a-practical-demo-part-1/)

Comment: This is a nonsense answer not related to the question.

Comment: @greenapps I guess you know only one word "nonsense" :), anyway that was the solution of my question so you can relax now. Thank you for your time and energy.